# How to create front camera "flash" effect using the iPhone screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to use iPhone 6s front camera's flash. I searched online and on Apple Docs but didn't find a useful explanation for how to use it. I'm currently making a custom front flash camera but I'm trying to use the official one used by Apple's camera.

Here's my code for my custom flash: (It's basically a white UIView that shows for a second and I set the phone's brightness to 1)

```
var flashview: UIView!
```

in viewDidLoad

```
    flashview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    flashview.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width/2, self.view.bounds.height/2)
    flashview.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    flashview.alpha = 0.0
    flashview.layer.zPosition = 100
    self.view.addSubview(flashview)
```

when photo is taken

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(1.0)
self.flashview.alpha = 1.0
sleep(1)
self.flashview.alpha = 0.9
sleep(1)
self.flashview.alpha = 0.0
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

Is there any possible way to use the same flash used in the official Apple camera?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're tempted to use `sleep()`, slap yourself and realize you're Doing It Wrong™.

You really need to look into [using animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html). This uses nicely optimized (by the system) timings that won't block the main thread (the user interface among other things) by waiting for a forced `sleep()` to finish.

Your case is a little more complicated because I don't believe `UIScreen`'s brightness is directly animatable. This means you'll need to create a [custom animatable property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW3) (maybe call it "flashLevel" or something), which in turn updates `UIScreen`'s brightness to match.

You should probably also note the user's brightness level *first*, animate to brightest second, then animate back to the user's level at the end of the "to maximum brightness" stage. I know it'd annoy *me* if an app screwed with my screen brightness and didn't put it back the way it was...

My best advice is to read the documentation to which I linked, try your best to get it working, then update your question to include the code you've tried and what's not working if you can't figure it out.